# 文字列が入った配列にハイフンと数字を追加したい。

Tags: ruby

[a..z]で用意した配列に‐と1～100までの数字を追加してa-1からz-100まで入った配列にしたいです。
プログラムを始めたばかりで理解しきれずわからないです。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　文字列というのは "a" から "z" まで入っているのでしょうか？　単純にアルファベット順に入っているとすると "z-100" ではなく "z-26" になりそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。('a'..'z')　でa~zまで入った配列を作り、その配列にそれぞれa-1,a-2~a~100,b-1~z-100といった用に配列に文字を追加していきたいです。説明が下手で誠に申し訳ありません。

Comment: [26個(a-z)][100個(1-100)]の2次元の配列を作るのか、a-1,...,a-100,b-1,..,b-100,c-1,... といった1次元の2600個の要素の配列を作るか、のどちらでしょうか。

Comment: a-1,...,a-100,b-1,..,b-100,c-1,.のように2600個の要素の配列を作る方です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
('a'..'z').flat_map { |c| (1..100).map { |n| "#{c}-#{n}" } }
# => ["a-1", "a-2", ...(省略)... , "z-98", "z-99", "z-100"]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。仕組みはまだ理解できていないものの確認できました。お忙しい中誠にありがとうございました。